# At least one output file must be specified in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I got this

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Geometry Dash\.tasbot\recorder\Mayhem playtest_1083172413.mp4"
-map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3
-c:a copy
-c:s copy
-c:v libx265
-crf 21
-preset veryfast
-tune animation
-color_primaries bt2020
-color_trc smpte2084
-colorspace bt2020nc
-profile:v main10
-pix_fmt yuv420p10le
-max_muxing_queue_size 9999
"C:\Steam\steamapps\common\Geometry Dash\.tasbot\recorder\Mayhem.mp4"
```

and the error is "At least one output file must be specified"
What's wrong?

Comment: Make sure the entire command is on one line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on windows you should end the lines with ^ if you want to split a command. Else it needs to a one line command without a new line.